# f-строка, поразрядное разделение числа через запятую

Tags: python, строки

вот имеется вот такой код:

```py
num = 1000000000
print(f'{num:,}')
1,000,000,000
```

Если выводить значение `print(f'{num:,}')` без двоеточия то вывод такой >> (1000000000,)
Как первая конструкция понимает, где ей расставить запятые?

Comment: В смысле как понимает? Разработчики питона запрограммировали питон так, что опция форматирования `,` включает деление на группы разрядов. Опции форматирования идут после двоеточия, а если двоеточия нет, то `num,` согласно синтаксису питона это просто кортеж из одного элемента, который и выводится как есть

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за пояснение